# C++ OpenCV, IplImage to double array

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, opencv

I'd like to :

(1) convert a 20x20 IplImage to a double array; then,

(2) I'd like to compute the error between this array and a 90x(20x20) 2 dimensional array of double type.

In Matlab, it is easily done like this:

```
(1)
I_thresh = I_gray<120;
% transformer matrice en vecteur
data(i*30+j,:) = (reshape(I_thresh',size(I_thresh,1)*size(I_thresh,2),1))';

(2)
function[classeEstim] = som_test(sM,testData,dim,prune)

labelsDbl = cvtCellChar2num(sM.labels);
X = zeros(size(sM.codebook,1),dim);

for i=1:size(testData,1)
    for j=1:size(sM.codebook,1)
        X(j,:) = abs(testData(1,1:dim) - sM.codebook(j,1:dim));
    end
    idx = (sum(X,2) == (min(sum(X,2))));
    classeEstim = labelsDbl(idx);
end
```

It is very easy in Matlab, but in C++ it's awful...

My code so far:

```
double* data;
int step;
CvSize size;
cvGetRawData(thresReduImg, (uchar**)&data, &step, &size);
step /= sizeof(data[0]);
for(int y = 0; y < size.height; y++, data += step )
    for(int x = 0; x < size.width; x++ )
        data[x] = (double)fabs(data[x]);
//classification
double** X = new double* [HEIGHT];
for (int i = 0; i <= HEIGHT; i++)
    X[i] = new double[WIDTH];
for(int i = 0; i <= HEIGHT; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j <= WIDTH; j++)
        X[i][j] = fabs(data[j] - codebook[i][j]);
```

This does not work, the program crashes and I can't identify the reason, but let's guess it's seg fault... Beside, there must be an elegant way to do what I want, a Matlab-like way...

I don't even know how to make sure that the datas in the data array are indeed
the values I want to compare to codebook (Self organized map classification)... In a perfect world, those datas should be the binary values computed by cvThreshold.

Any help will be very much appreciated!!!!!

Thanks !!

Comment: Nevermind, after a few hours it works... IplImage* dest = cvCreateImage(cvSize(20,20), 64, 1);
            cvConvert(thresReduImg, dest);
            double* data = (double*)dest->imageData;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is :

```
//Preprocessing here, to get a 20x20 binary image...

//transformer l'image seuillee en tableau 1D
double* score = new double[HEIGHT];
int index = 0;
//convertir contenu image seuille au format double FIRST ANSWER (1)
IplImage* dest = cvCreateImage(cvSize(20,20), 64, 1);
cvConvert(thresReduImg, dest);
double* data = (double*)dest->imageData;
//classification
double distance = 0;
//calcul des distances euclidiennes entre le vecteur d'entree
// et chacun des neurones de la carte de Kohonen. SECOND ANSWER (2)
for(int n = 0; n < HEIGHT; n++)
{
    for(int w = 0; w < WIDTH; w++)
    {
        //les donnees sont bien binaires, mais 0 ou 255
        // passer en 0 ou 1.
        if(data[w] == 255)
            data[w] = 1;
        //calcul pour chaque poids du neurone.
        distance += pow(data[w] - codebook[n][w],2);
    }
    //calcul distance euclidienne pour le neurone.
    score[n] = sqrt(distance);
    distance = 0;
}
//on cherche la distance minimale.
double value = score[0];
index = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < HEIGHT; i++)
{
    if(score[i] <= value)
    {
        value = score[i];
        index = i;
    }
}
// Continue... :)
```

Answer (score 2):

The elegant way would be to

### use the C++ API of OpenCV.

And then, you would not convert your image to an array which is dumb and cannot do anything, but convert your array to a cv::Mat, which is powerful!

And then you would have functions like sum, min etc. all at your disposal!

- You can initialize a cv::Mat with an std::vector just in the constructor! And then you can rewrap it to other dimensionality.
- You can initialize a cv::Mat from a C array by using std::copy. Yes, it works!
- You can use abs, operator-(), sum, min, zeros just like in your Matlab example. Even the thresholding works in a quite similar fashion, although there is also cv::threshold()

Don't hesitate. Start writing elegant and clean code **today**.

Comment: Please, read my code below. Elegant enough for me, no need of cvMat. Beside, I load "codebook" as a double bi-dimensional array, from a cvs. AND I need double, since I then compute Enclidian distance.

Comment: Mat_<double>... Get rid of IPLImage as soon as you can. Trust me.

Comment: OK! Thank you! Sorry for having been doing dumb things ;)

Comment: No need to be sorry, many people don't know the new API, but it is really worth looking into, otherwise you would miss out on most of the fun OpenCV can provide today.